# How to get Georesult value in SQL Server 2008 for the given address

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, geolocation, geocoding

Currently I am using SQL Server 2008.

Earlier we have "**MapInfo**" **software** installed in our server & configured that dll as extended stored procedure to my Sql Server.

In the recent upgradation the software were not instlled on the server.

But i have a requirement to update the **GEORESULT** Value based on the given Address.

Is there any way to udpate **GEORESULT** value with out *MAPINFO* software installation.

Currently I requre only US codes.

Here the Reference how Geocode works.

http://testdrive.mapinfo.com/TechSupp/MIProd.nsf/2dcd2e03799251b185257125006b1089/7013fe86de1c040185257019007782de?OpenDocument

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you mean by GEORESULT, I am guessing some sort of GPS Coordinate reference.   If so, Google Maps and BING both can do geolocating (getting GPS Coords for an address) via web service calls

Comment: @Sparky I have udpated the question. Please find the url.